# Is there a category for distributions with curved boundary?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I wonder if there is a mathematical term or way to describe a continuous distribution with a "curved" boundary. By "curved" I mean the distribution has compact support whose boundary cannot be described by straight lines (planes, etc) or intervals.

Positive example: if we truncate a mixture of two two-dimensional Gaussians at density $p(x)\ge0.01$, its boundary shape may look like digit 8 (without holes), as illustrated below:
[image]

The boundary shape has no line segments.

Negative example: the boundary of two-dimensional uniform is square $[a,b]\times[c,d]$.

Comment: "Positive example: a 2-D truncated $\dots$" can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @pointguard0 I mean two variables which both follow some truncated normal distributions. Is "two-dimensional" more clear?

Comment: the isolines of Gaussian distribution in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is an ellipse, but its support is not bounded. If you truncate by each coordinate then its support will be something like rectangle (in $n=2$).

Comment: @pointguard0 Thanks for your comments. You're correct. How about "truncated at radius r"?

Comment: Convex sets with boundaries not containing any intervals are sometimes called strictly convex, so "distributions with compact strictly convex support" may suit your needs.

Comment: you mean you truncate all the values that are beyond $\| x \| \le r$? then yes, you'll get ball as a boundary.

Comment: @Serg Thanks for your reply. After reading a few Wiki-pages, I assume "strictly" enforces that the boundary contains no line segments. But a distribution support can be both non-convex and "curved", right?